# How to change menu icon when scrolling to specific sections of the website?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, scroll

I have a one page site that uses a fixed menu icon. Some of the sections of the website are dark and some are light. Because of this I would like to change my menu icon to either the black or white version depending on what section of the site a user scrolls to.

For example my landing page has a white background, the menu icon being used is the black version. Below the landing page is my **"about"** section that has a black background. When the user scrolls to this section the menu icon should change to the white version instead.

Not sure if I am on the right track, but I have placed id tags for each section of my site and I have the menu icon referencing a css where the actual menu icon images are. I believe jquery is the answer to get it to actually change the image but I don't know how to code it.

Thank You.

THE HTML

```html
<!-- NAVIGATION MENU ICON -->
  
<div class="sb-navbar sb-slide">
    <!-- Right Slidebar control -->
    <div class="sb-toggle-right">
        <div class="icon_black"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE CSS

```css
  

.icon_black {
  width:72px;
  height:72px;
  background-image: url(../img/icon_black.png);
}
.icon_white {
  background-image: url(../img/icon_white.png);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:** (based on the further request of the OP in the comment section)

try this:

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>=$('#about').offset().top && $(document).scrollTop()<$('#work').offset().top){ //assuming the about section has an id called about (#about)
        $('.icon_black').removeClass('icon_black').addClass('icon_white');
    }
    else{
        $('.icon_white').removeClass('icon_white').addClass('icon_black');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work great! I am trying to add other instances to it though. For example it changed to the white version on the about section if I want it to change to the black version again on the next section, say the "work" section how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop() + 40; // 40px - Fixed nav height
    var closestElement = $(this).find('.section').filter( function() {
        return $(this).offset().top > scrollTop;      
    }).first();

    if( closestElement.hasClass('white'))
        $('#fixed').removeClass('black').addClass('white');
    else
        $('#fixed').removeClass('white').addClass('black');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9a5nc9kv/)